# Comparing models on the test data

Tags: model-selection, model-comparison

My understanding is that if you (1) have a sufficiently large test dataset, and (2) your models have the same likelihood (noise assumption), then you should compare/select the model likelihood (or log-likelihood) on the test data, unadjusted by AIC/BIC/DIC/etc.

Is there any justification for adjusting your likelihood for the test (or cross-validation) dataset for model selection? What is the best practice when such test dataset is available?

Comment: What do you mean by "adjusting model likelihood by AIC"? AIC is a measure (derived from likelihood) that has a different purpose and different domain than hypothesis testing.

Comment: @January please enlighten me. Isn't AIC used for selecting the number of parameters, which is a form of nested model selection?

Comment: Yes, AIC is used for model comparison (nested, not nested, overlapping...). It is an alternative to model selection with hypothesis testing. However, I still do not understand how do you adjust model likelihood (or test data) by AIC (this is not a criticism, I think it is either confusion or my lack of knowledge).

Comment: @January Perhaps I'm not using the right language here. I see AIC as penalizing the log-likelihood by the number of parameters. That's why I said "adjust". Feel free to edit the question for clarification.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe, though I'm still quite unsure on what you are asking. Maybe you could come up with an example?